# Не могу понять, почему такой вывод

Tags: java

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkEquality(100, 100);
        checkEquality(1000, 1000);

    }

    private static void checkEquality(Integer a, Integer b) {
        if (a == b) {
            System. out.println("equal");
        } else {
            System. out.println("different");
        }
    }

}
```

Не могу понять, почему выводит на экран equal different, хотя по идее, должно было быть equal equal?

Comment: Возможно дело в том, что оба `Integer`, а не `int`

Comment: @defaultlocale о, не знал что тут есть такой ответ

Comment: В ответе по ссылке обратите внимание на раздел «Integer pool» он непосредственно отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, сам удивился когда нашел

Comment: @defaultlocale спасибо большое!